# Exportando formatação de moeda com o ExcelBuilderJS

Tags: javascript, microsoft-excel

Estou usando o [ExcelBuilderJS](http://excelbuilderjs.com/) para produzir uma planilha do Excel sob demanda e oferecer como download ao cliente. Idealmente, isso precisa ser feito no cliente, não no servidor, e a biblioteca funciona muito bem nesse aspecto.

No entanto encontrei um problema ao criar células formatadas como contábil. Meu código pode ser resumido no seguinte:

```
var workbook = Excel.createWorkbook();
var sheet = workbook.createWorksheet({name: "Teste de Moeda"});
workbook.addWorksheet(sheet);

var currency = workbook.getStyleSheet().createFormat({
    format: "#.##0,00"
});

var data = [[ // Essa é a célula A1
    {value: 1234567.89, // Deve exibir como "1.234.567,89" no excel
     metadata: {style: currency.id}}
]];

sheet.setData(data);
sheet.setColumns([{width: 15}]);
saveAs(Excel.createFile(workbook, {type: "blob"}), "moeda.xlsx");
```

Aqui um fiddle que demonstra ele funcionando:

### http://jsfiddle.net/6ndTq/

O ponto problemático é que quando abro o resultado, vejo o seguinte:

[image: 1234567,89000]

Abrindo a formatação da célula, há o seguinte:

[image: #,##000]

Claramente não foi `#,##000` o que eu digitei no código. Se for manualmente trocar para `#.##0,00` que é o que está no código, o formato aparece como deve ser:

[image: #.##0,00]

Experimentei algumas variações dessa formatação sem ter sucesso. O que posso fazer?

Answer (score 1):

## Vire à esquerda para chegar na direita.

Para obter o formato `#.##0,00` deve-se usar o formato `#,##0.00` no código. O motivo? Difícil dizer. Talvez seja que todo o arquivo deve obrigatoriamente ser salvo com locale americano e o excel faz a tradução no momento de ler o arquivo.

### http://jsfiddle.net/6ndTq/1/

[image]